# find order of group $G= \{ a,d : a^{2n}=e, d^2 =a^n,da =a^{-1}d $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n$ be a prime, compute order of each element of each element of

$$G= \{ a,d : a^{2n}=e, d^2 =a^n,da =a^{-1}d $$

what is  possible order of each element ?

number of elements of that order

the elements of that order

---

**Progress?**

$$G = \{ a^i d^j: 0 \leq i \leq 2n-1,0 \leq k \leq 1 \} $$

breaking it down as

$$\begin{matrix}
a^0 d^0 & a^1 d^0 \dots a^{2n-1}
\\ a^0 d^1 & a^1 d^1 \dots a^{2n-1} d
\end{matrix} $$

Grabbing elment from the second row and raising to the second power

$$ (a^i d)(a^id)= a^i d a^i d= a^i a^{-i} dd= d^2$$

so raising it to the 4th power

$$(a^i d)^4= (a^i d)^2 (a^i d)^2=d^2 d^2 = a^n a^n=a^{2n}=e $$

grabbing elements of first row

$$ \begin{aligned}
|a^1|=2p
\\|a^2|=p
\\ |a^3|=2p
\\ |a^4|=p
\\ |a^5|=2p
\\ \vdots
\end{aligned}
 $$

Looking at cases

$1$ no prime since unit
consider $p=2$

$$ \begin{aligned}
|a^1|=2p
\\|a^2|=p
\\ |a^3|=2p
\end{aligned}
 $$

considre $p=3$

$$ \begin{aligned}
|a^1|=2p
\\|a^2|=p
\\ |a^3|=2p
\\ |a^4|=p
\\ |a^5|=2p
\end{aligned}
 $$

consider p=5

$$ \begin{aligned}
|a^1|=2p
\\|a^2|=p
\\ |a^3|=2p
\\ |a^4|=p
\\ |a^5|=2p
\\ |a^6|=p
\\ |a^7|=2p
\\ |a^8|=p
\\ |a^9|=2p
\end{aligned}
 $$

the pattern is that there are p of order $2p$ and $p-1$ of order $p$

**But this is not technically a proof. Want to do something with induction but not sure how to properly word it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $|a| = 2n.$

Consider $|a^i|$.

We need values $k,l$ such that ${(a^i)}^k$ = $(a^{2n})^l$, i.e. $ik = 2nl$. This happens at $\text{LCM}(i,2n)$.

However $n$ is prime, so by dividing through by $i$ we get $k$ is the pattern you suggest.

I'll let you calculate the result for elements involving $d$ on your own.